# Gin Error panic: wildcard route conflicts with existing children

Tags: rest, go, routes, web-frameworks

I using https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin and I am trying to implement nested routes like this:

```
// SetupRouter initialize routes and handlers
func SetupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/", controllers.Welcome)

    r.GET("/resources", controllers.GetResources)   
    r.GET("/resources/otherroute", controllers.GetOResources)   
    r.GET("/resources/:id", controllers.GetResourcesByID)   
    r.GET("/resources/:id/sub-resources", GetSubResources)
    r.GET("/resources/:id/sub-resources/:srid", GetSubResourcesByID)
    r.GET("/resources/:id/sub-resources/:srid/ssub-resources", GetSSubResources)
    r.GET("/resources/:id/sub-resources/:srid/ssub-resources/:ssrid", GetSSubResourcesByID)

    // .... etc.

    return r
}
```

but I am getting weird errors:

```
[GIN-debug] GET    /                         --> github.com/badis/so-

gin-nested-routes/controllers.Welcome (3 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /resources                --> github.com/badis/so-gin-nested-routes/controllers.GetResources (3 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /resources/otherroute     --> github.com/badis/so-gin-nested-routes/controllers.GetOResources (3 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /resources/:id            --> github.com/badis/so-gin-nested-routes/controllers.GetResourcesByID (3 handlers)
panic: wildcard route ':id' conflicts with existing children in path '/resources/:id'

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*node).insertChild(0xc0002516c0, 0xc0001edc01, 0xc0002325eb, 0x3, 0xc0002325e0, 0xe, 0xc000224300, 0x3, 0x3)
    /home/badis/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/tree.go:294 +0x807
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*node).addRoute(0xc0002516c0, 0xc0002325e0, 0xe, 0xc000224300, 0x3, 0x3)
    /home/badis/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/tree.go:255 +0x4ea
```

and I am not able to find a satisfying solution in or outside SO.

If you want to reproduce issue quickly, take a look here: https://github.com/badis/so-question-gin-routes

Comment: I believe you cannot mix dynamic segments with static ones. You can use either `/resources/otherroute` or `/resources/:id` but not both.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```golang
// SetupRouter initialize routes and handlers
func SetupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/", controllers.Welcome)

    r.GET("/resources", controllers.GetResources)   
    r.GET("/resources/otherroute", controllers.GetOResources)   
    resources := r.Group("/resources/:rid")
    {
        resources.GET("", controllers.GetResourcesByID)
        resources.GET("otherroute", controllers.GetOResources)
        resources.GET("sub-resources", controllers.GetSubResources)
        subResources := resources.GET("sub-resources/:srid")
        {
            subResources.GET("", GetSubResourcesByID)
            subResources.GET("/ssub-resources", GetSSubResources)
            subResources.GET("/ssub-resources/:ssrid", GetSSubResourcesByID)
        }
    }

    // .... etc.

    return r
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gin can't distinguish `/resources/otherroute` from `/resources/:id` because `otherroute` can be interpreted as `:id` and therefor you have a conflict.

Comment: It would work perfectly in express.js, but I can see that Gin doesn't have it yet. it could check for `/resources/otherroute` . if it doesn't match it put anything found inside `:id`. as long as it doesn't have more parts like: `/resources/:id/sub-resources`

Comment: Yes, prioritizing the routes would make sense. But there might be a reason why it's not done. Either way, perhaps accept the answer or close to question :-)